# How to insert association/child data into Ext.data.list as separate entries

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm using ST2 and using MVC. I'm very new to ExtJS and Sencha, so am not au fair the best practices for many things - and on this issue I've hit a dead end despite research.

I'll use a toy example to illustrate my issue below, but essentially I have a relationship as follows (which all works correctly from an association perspective).

```
Business X  -- Location A
           |
            -- Location N
```

### The Problem

I want to then populate the data into (for instance) an `Ext.dataview.List`, but to process it such that each location (i.e. child location) has its own *separate entry* in the table; not just a simple `itemTpl` formatting a single entry. However, at present I can't find any way to do that. Is it possible to hook into a `List` and format the data as I want, or should I be creating a new store? Ideally I want to make best use of the associations.

As a rough example, each entry would look like this, with some parent data and some child data:

```
    ---------------------------
    |Smith Co - 1 Smith Street|
    ---------------------------
    |Smith Co - 24 High Street|
    ---------------------------
    |Tea[...] - 12 Tea Leaf   |
    ---------------------------
    |Tea[...] - 3 Bis Kit     |
    ---------------------------
```

### Example Code

#### Raw data

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Smith Co",
      "locations":[
         {
            "address":"1 Smith Street"
         },
         {
            "address":"24 High Street"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"Tea So Good",
      "locations":[
         {
            "address":"12 Tea Leaf"
         },
         {
            "address":"3 Bis Kit"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

#### Location Model

```
Ext.define('Example.model.Location', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
      fields: [
        { name: 'address', type: 'string' }
      ],
      proxy: { ... }, // Rest proxy that loads data as shown above.

      BelongsTo: 'Example.model.Company'
    }
});
```

#### Company Model

```
Ext.define('Example.model.Company', {
   extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

   config: {
     fields: [
       { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
       { name: 'name', type: 'string' }
     ],
     proxy: { ... }, // Rest proxy that loads data as shown above.

     hasMany: { model: 'Example.model.Location', name: 'locations' }

   }
});
```

#### Store

```
Ext.define('Example.store.Companies', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    require: 'Example.model.Company',

    config: {
        model: 'Example.model.Company'
    } 
});
```

#### Controller

```
// (works correctly, relationships are traversable)
// Companies store is looked up and loaded in #launch()
```

#### View

```
Ext.define('Example.view.CompaniesList', {
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    xtype: 'companieslist', 

    config: {
        layout: 'fit',
        store: 'Businesses',
        itemTpl: [
            // Tpl is only to format inside each element
        ]
    }
});
```

---

Solution Edit (15th Sept 2013):

#### Solution

I used the solution @rixo suggested (and I had been hoping to avoid in the original question).

I created a separate store for the list, and loaded the data I need into it by using a `load` listener on the `Companies` store. This seems to be the most graceful solution available, although it means you may need to add extra logic in various places to ensure it remains satisfactorily synchronised.

By pushing the location objects themselves into the new store the associations remain intact (i.e. you can still do `location.getCompany()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, create another store for locations.

You may have tried a template like this:

```
itemTpl: [
    '{name}',
    '<tpl for="locations">',
        ', {address}',
    '</tpl>'
]
```

But that will indeed only display the information, it won't let you interact with each location as an individual list item.

You could get it working by hacking the view's [`doRefresh`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/source/DataView.html#Ext-dataview-DataView-method-doRefresh) method, but that's just going against the lib's intention and other developer' expectations.

Maybe the problem is that you can get the data only in this format, that is with locations as children of companies, and you can't get the server to send you a flat list of companies. In that case, I think the most meaningful approach would be to customize a reader to flatten locations from companies, and feed a standalone location store. The [`extractData`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/source/Reader.html#Ext-data-reader-Reader-method-extractData) method seems a very promising start for that (see [how the JSON reader uses it](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/source/Json.html#Ext-data-reader-Json-method-extractData) to implements its root property).

Comment: Potentially tackling this from another direction, could it be possible to access the store for the locations? The problem here seems to be that because the data is loading from a single location, there is no way I can find of accessing the store of locations separately. The issue in general seems a fairly obvious OO/ORM problem, I'm very surprised there isn't a standard solution to it.

Comment: There is no central store for locations. Ext's store are not the client side equivalent of database tables, which can be misleading. With the associations you have configured, Ext will create one location store for *each company*. That's why you have to create one. You can feed it by hacking a reader, as I suggested, or you can create the data by looping through the company records and then each of their locations if you want to avoid the extra request.

Comment: Many thanks for your thoughts, I'm going to try a few different approaches and see which suits best. Then I'll amend my question with anything useful I discover and select the best response(s). Unfortunately I don't have enough rep to UV you at present.